# Entering command 'sqlplus' results in 'sqlplus: command not found'

Tags: oracle-10g, linux

I've recently installed Fedora 19 on an older PC, to serve as a test server of sorts. After a lot of hiccups, I was able to install Oracle 10g XE.

Because I'm using Linux - which I, admittedly, have little experience of - I used the command line (rpm) to install the file.

Everything proceeded without a hitch, though I didn't understand much of it.

When I try to log in using *sqlplus*, though, the command line returns:

```
sqlplus: command not found
```

Now, I did some digging around. First thing I did was to check if the server is up and running. So I entered the following:

```
sudo etc/init.d/oracle-xe start
```

Take note that being a Linux noob, I actually have no idea if this command holds true to every Linux installation. All I know is that it works on my friend's PC. My PC, on the other hand, produces some interesting results:

```
Starting oracle-xe (via systemctl): Job for oracle-xe.service failed
```

Tried the following:

```
sudo etc/init.d/oracle-xe start
```

With the following results:

> /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/bin/lsnrctl:
>   /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: no such file or directory

I don't know who this ELF guy is, but at this point, I assumed I'm screwed. After more research on the internet, I found out something about Oracle variables and paths not setting themselves correctly, but none of them were of any help.

[sqlplus: command not found](http://rajanimohanty.blogspot.com/2013/05/bash-sqlplus-command-not-found-error.html)

[Go To Oracle Home](http://www.dbas-oracle.com/2011/10/bash-sqlplus-command-not-found.html)

Any ideas?

Additional Info:

- Oracle Database Installed: Oracle XE 10.2.0.1.1 i386 (rpm file)
- Operating System: Fedora x86-84, Release 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Oracle Installation Guide](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/to_toc?pathname=install.102/b15660/toc.htm&remark=portal%20%28Getting%20Started%29) contains a [list of packages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b15660/pre_install.htm#sthref111) that need to be installed prior to Oracle. A common cause of this problem might also be if you are trying to install a 32bit version of Oracle on a 64bit version of Linux.

Answer (score 1):

For XE version of the database you must have these packages installed

> glibc  libaio

You'll need both 32 and 64 version of these packages, because your OS is 64 and database is 32 bit.
Check out official documentation for XE
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/install.102/b25144/toc.htm#CIHFEBGE

For environment variables setting check out this part of the link above.

> 4.3 Setting the Oracle Database XE Server Environment Variables